# How to make these clients not block output after sending a port number (java multithreaded socket)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Here is the screenshot of the **desired** result: (sever on top, one client on bottom left, one client on bottom right)

[image]*

Here is the screenshot of the program's **current result**:
(server on top, one client on bottom left, one client on bottom right):[image]

In the screenshot above, in the bottom left and bottom right window, the command line arguments `java ChatClient -l 4021 -p 3000` have two numbers (`4021` and `3000`). The number `4021` is what the top window (server) needs to file transfer so it has to be sent to the server somehow but unfortunately the sending of this number probably causes something to block which means that the correct output of `What is your name?` is never shown which indicates that something must be going wrong so I placed the line `System.out.println("this line in chatClient.java is before the inputLine.readLine() is called");` for debugging purposes.

**My question is**: What changes can I make to the following code that would allow the desired screenshot's output to be displayed instead of the current screenshot's output (i. e. the output of `What is your name?`, `Enter your message` etc)?

`ChatClient.java` code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatClient implements Runnable 
{
  public static int once = 0;
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  private static Socket fileSocket = null;
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  private static DataInputStream is = null;
  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;
  public static String[] namesList = new String[10];
  public int iteration = 0;
  public static String[] responses = new String[50];
  public int responseCount = 0;
  public int filePort = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      int filePort = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
     for(int i = 0; i < namesList.length; i++)
     {
         namesList[i] = "";
     }
     for(int j = 0; j < responses.length; j++)
     {

         responses[j] = "";
     }
    int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);
    String host = "localhost";

    try 
    {

      clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);

      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
          + host);
    }
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null)
    {
      try 
      {

        while (!closed)
        {
             if(once==0)
             {
                 System.out.println("this line in chatClient.java is before outputstream is created");
                  OutputStream os2 = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os2);
                  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                  bw.write("The file port is: `"+ filePort);
                  System.out.println("The file port is: `" + filePort);

                  once=3;
                  os.println("The file port is: `" + filePort);


                  os.println(inputLine.readLine() );


             }
                once=3;
        }
        new Thread(new ChatClient()).start();

        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run()
{
    String responseLine = "";
    try 
    {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
      {
          if(responseLine.equals("x") || responseLine.equals("X"))
          {
              System.exit(0);
          }
          if(responseLine.equals("Who owns the file?") && !responseLine.isEmpty() && responseLine != null)
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responses[responseCount] = "234782375920192831";

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("Which file do you want?"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("What is your name?"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("m") || responseLine.equals("M"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              System.out.println("Enter your message: ");
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine.equals("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n"))
          {

              responseCount++;
              System.out.println(responseLine);  
              responses[responseCount] = responseLine;

          }
          if(responseLine != null && !responseLine.isEmpty() && !responseLine.equals("What is your name?") && !responseLine.equals("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n") && !responseLine.equals("Who owns the file?") && !responseLine.equals("Which file do you want?"))
          {
              responseCount++;
              if(responses[responseCount-1].equals("234782375920192831"))
              {
                  namesList[iteration] = responseLine;
                  iteration++;
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println(responseLine);  
                  responses[responseCount] = responseLine;
              }
          }
      }
      closed = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

`ChatServer.java` code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ChatServer
{
  public static List<String> listName = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  List<String> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  public static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  public static ServerSocket fileSocket = null;
  public static Socket clientSocket = null;
  public static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  public static final ClientThreads[] threads = new ClientThreads[maxClientsCount];
  public static String[] namesList = new String[10];
 // public ChatClient arrayOfNames = new ChatClient;
  public static int filePort = 0;

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      synchronized (listName)
        {
            //Iterator i = listName.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block

             Iterator<String> i = listName.listIterator();
        }
      if(args.length <3)
      {
          int portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
          System.out.println("waiting for connections on port " + portNumber + " ...\n ");
      }
    try 
    {

      int portNumber1 = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber1);
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (true) 
    {
      try
      {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;



        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String something;
        System.out.println("this line is executed in chatserver.java  before in.readLine()");

        something = in.readLine();
        String string = something;
        String[] parts = string.split("`");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1]; 
        System.out.println("The file port is: " + part2);
        filePort = strToInt(part2);
        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
            if (threads[i] == null)
            {
                String name = "";
                (threads[i] = new ClientThreads(clientSocket, threads, name, namesList, listName, filePort)).start();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == maxClientsCount)
        {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
          os.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
  public static int strToInt( String str )
  {
     int i = 0;
     int num = 0;
     boolean isNeg = false;

     //Check for negative sign; if it's there, set the isNeg flag
     if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
         isNeg = true;
         i = 1;
     }

     //Process each character of the string;
     while( i < str.length()) {
         num *= 10;
         num += str.charAt(i++) - '0'; //Minus the ASCII code of '0' to get the value of the charAt(i++).
     }

     if (isNeg)
         num = -num;
     return num;
 }

}
```

`ClientThreads.java` code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
class ClientThreads extends Thread
{ 
  public int once = 0;
  public String name1 = "";
  private String clientName = null;
  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final ClientThreads[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;
  public int position = 0;
  public int filePort = 0;
  public static List<String> listName = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  List<String> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
  public String[] namesList = new String[10];
  public ClientThreads(Socket clientSocket, ClientThreads[] threads, 
          String name, String[] namesList, List<String> listName, int filePort)
  {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
    this.name1 = name;
    this.namesList = namesList;
    this.filePort = filePort;

  }



  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run() 
  {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    ClientThreads[] threads = this.threads;
    synchronized (listName)
    {
        //Iterator i = listName.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block

         ListIterator<String> i = listName.listIterator();
    }
    try 
    {
     if(once==0)
     {
          OutputStream os2 = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
          OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os2);
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
          once=3;
     }
        once=3;
      System.out.println("This line is executed before inputstream and output stream are created");
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      String name;
      while (true) 
      {
        os.println("What is your name?");
        name = is.readLine().trim();


          break;
      }
      if(listName != null)
      {
          synchronized(listName)
          {
              if(!listName.contains(name))
              {
                  listName.add(name);
                  os.println("The name " + name + " has been added to the list. "
                    + "The list now contains " + listName);
              }

          }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this)
          {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null)
          {
            threads[i].os.println(name + " has connected.");
            os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");
          }
        }
      }
      while (true)
      {
        synchronized(listName)
        {
            if(!listName.contains(name))
            {
                listName.add(name);
                os.println("The name " + name + " has been added to the list. "
                        + "The list now contains " + listName);
            }

        }
        String line = is.readLine();
        if (line.startsWith("/quit")) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");
        }

        if(line.equals("x") || line.equals("X"))
        {
            os.println("x");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(line.equals("m") || line.equals("M"))
        {
          os.println("Enter your message: ");
        }
        if(line.equals("f") || line.equals("F"))
        {
          os.println("Who owns the file?");
          boolean keep = true;
          while (keep == true)
          {
            String fileOwner = is.readLine();

            if(fileOwner !=null && !fileOwner.isEmpty())
            {
                os.println(fileOwner);
                System.out.println(fileOwner);
                System.out.println();
                //namesList[position] = fileOwner;

            //  os.println("The client connected name: " + fileOwner + 
                //      " has been added to position " + position +
                //      " in the namesList array " + namesList[position]);
                //position++;





                keep = false;
                os.println("Which file do you want?");
                boolean keep2 = true;
                while(keep2==true)
                {
                  String filename = is.readLine();
                  if(filename !=null && !filename.isEmpty())
                  {
                     // os.println(filename);
                      keep2 = false;
                      os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");

                  }
                }

            }
          }
        }
        if (line.startsWith("@")) 
        {
          String[] words = line.split("\\s", 2);
          if (words.length > 1 && words[1] != null) 
          {
            words[1] = words[1].trim();
            if (!words[1].isEmpty())
            {
              synchronized (this)
              {
                for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
                {
                  if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this  && threads[i].clientName != null && threads[i].clientName.equals(words[0])) 
                  {
                      threads[i].os.println(name + ": " + words[1]);

                    this.os.println(name + ": " + words[1]);
                    this.os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");

                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        else 
        {
          synchronized (this)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) 
            {
              if (!line.equals("x") && !line.equals("X") && !line.equals("f") && !line.equals("F") && !line.equals("m") && !line.equals("M") && threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null && !threads[i].clientName.equals("m") && !threads[i].clientName.equals("M")) 
              {
                threads[i].os.println(name + ": " + line + "\n");
                this.os.println("Enter an option: 'm' = message, 'f' = file request, 'x' = exit\n");
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this && threads[i].clientName != null)
          {
            threads[i].os.println(name + "has disconnected.");
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
        {
          if (threads[i] == this) 
          {
            threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      is.close();
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: What changes can I make to the code listed above in order to obtain the desired result screenshot?

Comment: That's a lot of code and links to follow.  You've got more chance of getting an answer if you can provide a minimal example.

Comment: @SteveSmith basically I think it has to do with .readLine() being blocked by some other stream (I'm not sure which), or at least I know that the line before .readLine() is printing out the  `System.out.println("this line in chatClient.java is before the inputLine.readLine() is called")` before the line that's being blocked but it's still a lot so I understand if it gets downvoted or removed